# Iterative methods for solving a linear system with many right-hand sides

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I am trying to solve $A X = B$ for $X$ using some iterative method, where $A$ is a large, square, full rank n-by-n matrix and $X, B$ are also both n-by-n matrices. I'm aware of the large literature on numerical solutions to the case where $X$ and $B$ are both vectors, but haven't been able to find guidance on the more general case.

I could transform the general equation into a linear system, either by solving for each column of $X$ separately or equivalently by solving the vectorized version:
$$(I_n \otimes A)  x^*= b^*,$$ 
where $x^*$ and $b^*$ are vectors constructed by stacking the columns of $X$ and $B$. Unfortunately I have about a million columns and each column takes five minutes to solve, and thus solving the system in such a way would take roughly 9 years and 7 months. Is a quicker method available?

Comment: Some notation: $Ax=b$ is a standard linear system with a single right-hand side, while $AX=B$ is a standard linear system with multiple right-hand sides. The term "matrix equation" does not apply to these cases. An important example is the Sylvester matrix equation, i.e., $AX+XB^T=C$. I have edited your question accordingly.

Comment: What method are you using when you solve for just one column of $X$? What's the value of $n$? How long does it take to compute $AX$ for a given vector $X$?

Comment: Are you aware that solving this would not only take 9 years but also 16PB of storage space (assuming double precision)?

Comment: @littleO -- I'm using Biconjugate gradient descent. It takes about five minutes to solve one column.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel -- good point! Clearly something to think about. I'm mostly interested in the diagonal of the solution matrix, though not exclusively. Will try to think as to whether my RHS can be approximated in some lower-dimensional way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should investigate these keywords: "block Krylov methods" and "Krylov subspace recycling".

Block Krylov methods are designed for your situation, i.e., multiple right-hand sides.

In general, you can use the Krylov subspace generated during the solution of one system to accele-rate the solution of another system with the same coefficient matrix. This procedure is known as Krylov subspace recycling.